# ChartJS: call the property of an array object in the tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js, tooltip

[image]

Hello folks,
I'm stuck with my chart.
I want to display the value of the object property "value" in the tooltip but I can't figure out how.

 Just to be clear, in the tooltip i want to see "CONTRAZIONE: 66".

 I need to keep the y with value 2.5 for the correct placement in the chart, but if in the tooltip callback I return tooltipItems.yLabel for the label property I get "CONTRAZIONE: 2.5".

 Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the tooltip callbacks to achieve what you want, see example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
        x: 'val1',
        y: 2,
        value: 20
      }, {
        x: 'val2',
        y: 2.5,
        value: 25
      }, {
        x: 'val3',
        y: 3,
        value: 35
      }],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ttItem) => (`${ttItem.dataset.label}: ${ttItem.dataset.data[ttItem.dataIndex].value}`)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```